# How do I create optional references/embeds in Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, nosql

We have an Item database in Mongoid where we store contextual, optional extra fields for different items, eg:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
end
```

so I can do something like:

```
a = Item.new
a.name = "Potato Chips"
a[:flavor] = "Barbecue"
a.save
b = Item.new
b.name = "Underwear"
b[:size] = "XL"
b.save
> Item.first.flavor
 => "Barbecue" 
> Item.last.size
 => "XL"
```

However, say we wanted to do:

```
class Flavor
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :ingredients, type: Array
end
```

If you did:

```
f = Flavor.create({name: "Barbecue", ingredients: ["salt", "sugar"]})
a[:flavor] = f
a.save
```

You get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `__bson_dump__' for #<Flavor:0x007fb34d3c1718>
```

How do I make it so I can go:

```
Item.first.flavor.ingredients[0]
```